# Ubuntu server shuts down automaticly

Tags: ubuntu

My ubuntu server (vserver) is shutting down automaticly sometimes and i don't know why.

syslog.log before shutting down:

```
Aug 15 06:09:01 vmd744 CRON[3403]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -print0 | xargs -n 200 -r -0 rm)
Aug 15 06:17:01 vmd744 CRON[3556]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 15 06:20:01 vmd744 CRON[3575]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
```

kern.log

```
Aug 15 06:00:01 vmd744 kernel: [491778.130573] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
Aug 15 06:00:01 vmd744 kernel: [491778.131826] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 15 06:00:12 vmd744 kernel: [491789.001058] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

debug:

```
Aug 15 04:00:11 vmd744 kernel: [484607.162921] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Aug 15 05:00:12 vmd744 kernel: [488197.997212] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Aug 15 06:00:12 vmd744 kernel: [491789.001058] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

daemon.log

```
Aug 15 06:00:01 vmd744 init: ssh main process (3273) terminated with status 255
Aug 15 06:00:01 vmd744 ntpdate[3268]: step time server 91.189.94.XXX offset -0.022252 sec
Aug 15 06:00:06 vmd744 ntpdate[3312]: step time server 91.189.94.XXX offset -0.000129 sec
```

apache-error.log

```
[Mon Aug 15 03:05:44 2011] [error] [client 95.211.110.XXX] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
[Mon Aug 15 04:06:59 2011] [error] [client 220.181.108.XXX] File does not exist: /var/www/contentlion/css/robots.txt
[Mon Aug 15 04:17:19 2011] [error] [client 58.218.199.XXX] script '/var/www/proxyheader.php' not found or unable to stat
```

apache-access.log

```
188.138.106.XXX - - [15/Aug/2011:03:49:42 +0200] "PUT /webdav/7458477777897774583 HTTP/1.1" 405 632 "-" "Sardine/UNAVAILABLE"
58.218.199.XXX - - [15/Aug/2011:04:17:19 +0200] "GET http://www.hardjob.net/proxyheader.php HTTP/1.1" 404 535 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2011:04:27:38 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And at which timestamp did the server go down? Where are the logs indicating the shutdown? Is there a cleaner in the morning cleaning the power button?

Comment: by vserver, do you mean this is a virtualized host or guest? When you said it is automatically shutting down, does it shut down every day at the same time (approximately) or is it variable?

Comment: I'd like to see more of the syslog & cronlog.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I don't know, when the server gone down, I think it was about 6:20 because there was the last log entry. It's a virtual host. It doesn't shut down every day, but until today it was 3 times. Some more syslog: http://stevieswebsite.de/syslog.txt I can't find the cronlog.

Comment: Is it "shut down" (powered off quietly) or "crashed" (with potentially useful information on the (virtual) console)?  If it's a virtual server is it possible your provider is knocking it down for some reason?

Comment: I don't exactly know, if it's crashed or not. I just noticed, that it's offline and my provider said, it was shutted down (not from then)

Answer (score 0):

I did not see anything in the syslog.  Would it be possible to see more of the other logs?
I would also disable IPV6, simply because it looks like your provider does not offer it.

Comment: There are no other relevant logs. I disable IPv6 and wait for the next shut down. Thanks for your help!